# How to open any android device front camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to open my front camera in my app but I can't open 2 different devices with the same code.
How I should code to open **any** device front camera?

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REGISTRO_PONTO_IMAGE_CAM);
```

This is the code that I'm using, but **it does not work** for many devices.

Comment: in which device not working?

Comment: LG G4, moto g4 and others that i'm try, this code only works for Samsung =/

Comment: nothing, just not open

Comment: please mention the Android version of both devices, if you are using android version equal or above 6(Marshmallow) you have to request permission for camera first

Comment: 5.0.2 for both of them

Comment: "How I should code to open any device front camera?" -- use the camera APIs directly. As [we discussed previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226597/open-frontal-face-camera-in-android), there is nothing in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol for requiring a particular camera.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function rather than opening front camera from Intent

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCamera() {
int cameraCount = 0;
Camera camera = null;
Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
    Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}

return camera;
}
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`dont forget to add these permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"    android:required="false" />
```

> If code throws `RunTimeException` **An error occurred while connecting
>   to camera:** it means some other application  is using camera hardware
>   reference and didn't release it and android allow only one application
>   to use harware at the same time so try to call release() when you are done using the camera,
>   otherwise it will remain locked and be unavailable to other
>   applications. ***so you have to reboot the device to handle this Exception***.

Comment: get me this:
CameraService::connect X (pid 17799) rejected (existing client).
An error occurred while connecting to camera: 1
getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10124 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output

Comment: @gFontaniva restart your device and then try hopefully error will be gone